# Allow !! when it is certain it will not throw an NPE

Tags: kotlin, operator-keyword, assertion, non-nullable

I'm looking at a pull request, which contains `!!` - the not-null assertion operator. Should it be approved?

The nullable value itself will indeed never be null. I can't think of a better argument than 'It feels wrong'

```
private val hasFinishedSubject = BehaviorSubject.create<Boolean>()

init {
    hasFinishedSubject.onNext(false)
}

val hasFinishedScanner: Boolean
    get() = hasFinishedSubject.value!!
```

Since `hasFinishedSubject` is initialized on construction, `hasFinishedSubject.value` will never be null

It could be replaced with f.i.:

```
val hasFinishedScanner: Boolean
    get() = hasFinishedSubject.value ?: false
```

but this false is redundant and could lead to bugs as well. What is the most clean?

Comment: We went for `get() = hasFinishedSubject.value as Boolean`.
All three options throw an exception at the exact same moment, but this seemed the most clean and communicates that it was thought through.

Comment: There's a [`BehaviorSubject.createDefault`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html#createDefault-T-) method which can eliminate your constructor.

Comment: Thank you @EugenPechanec. It's a shame that .value still is nullable, but it indeed is an improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin compiler respect nullability annotations from Java, e.g. `@Nullable` or `@NotNull` from either JSR-305 or intelliJ.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations

It may probably make sense to include these annotations into the `BehaviorSubject` class if you have control over it.

From the other side, there are Platform types in Kotlin, that are used to simplify nullability check in Java interop.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types

From my point of view, using `!!` with Kotlin code should be avoided, in Kotlin there are enough ways to make your code Nullable-correct.

For the Java interop - it may happen. But instead of using `!!` one may use something more meaningful, like what you suggested above.

I would probably have written something like:

```
val hasFinishedScanner: Boolean
    get() = hasFinishedSubject.value ?: error("No value")
```

Here the `error` function has return type `Nothing`, in fact, it throws an exception.

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` is an RxJava class and I do not have control over it. However, it is annotated with `@Nullable` already. `.value` can be null, but won't be in our implementation.

Comment: I inderaad like that the error adds meaning and I will suggest that.